# Reading a POST set from jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to this so sorry if I have a hard time asking this question or my terminology is not correct. I have a very simple web service that takes a json string, does some stuff, then echos a result in json:

```
$jsonStr = '';

if(isset($_POST['request']))
{
    $request = $_POST['request'];
    $jsonStr = parseJsonStr($request);
}
else //nothing posted return failed
    $jsonStr = '{"Result" : "Failed No Data", "Code" : 400}';

$resultsArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

if(array_key_exists('Code', $resultsArr))
{
    $http_response_code = array(
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'CREATED',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        500 => 'Internal Error',
        501 => 'Not implemented'
    );

    header('HTTP/1.1 '.$resultsArr['Code'].' '.$http_response_code[ $resultsArr['Code'] ]);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo($jsonStr);
```

Using php and curl I can post to it and it works:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('request' => $jsonStr ));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status >= 300 ) //I expect mostly 201
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));

curl_close($curl);
echo($json_response);
```

I am trying to do the same post with jQuery .ajax, but I am having trouble getting it to post to the 'request' field 
Here is what I have so far:

```
//edit I didn't include this on my original post 
var jsonStr = '{"userName":"' + $('input[name="username"]').val() + '",' + '"password":"' + $('input[name="pwd"]').val() ...
//end edit
$.ajax(
{ // ajax call starts
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ request: jsonStr }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#retJson').html(''); // Clear #retJson div
        $('#retJson').append('<br/>' + data + '<br/>');
    },
    error: function(data, errorThrown)
    { 
        $('#retJson').html(''); // Clear #retJson div
        $('#retJson').append('data:' + data +  ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown); 
    } 
});
```

I am getting my 'Failed No Data error' so I know that it is connecting to it, but I don't think it is posting anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

I figured out my issue which lead to another question it works if I changed to this:

```
$.ajax(
{ // ajax call starts
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: 
    { 
        request: '{"userName":"' + $('input[name="username"]').val() + '",' + '"password":"' + $('input[name="pwd"]').val() ...
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('#retJson').html(''); // Clear #retJson div
        $('#retJson').append('<br/>' + data + '<br/>');
    },
    error: function(data, errorThrown)
    { 
        $('#retJson').html(''); // Clear #retJson div
        $('#retJson').append('data:' + data +  ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown); 
    } 
});
```

My question is how do I use a var in the .ajax?

Comment: What happens when you set `dataType: 'json'` as an option in your `$.ajax` call?

Comment: It does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a PHP and HTML file to test the entire use case.

```
<?php

    function parseJsonStr($request) {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $request = stripslashes($request);
        }
        return '{"Code":200}';
    }

    $jsonStr = '';

    if(isset($_POST['request'])) {
        $request = $_POST['request'];
        $jsonStr = parseJsonStr($request);
    } else {

        //nothing posted return failed
        $jsonStr = '{"Result" : "Failed No Data", "Code" : 400}';
    }

    $resultsArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

    if(array_key_exists('Code', $resultsArr)) {
        $http_response_code = array(
            200 => 'OK',
            201 => 'CREATED',
            400 => 'Bad Request',
            401 => 'Unauthorized',
            403 => 'Forbidden',
            404 => 'Not Found',
            500 => 'Internal Error',
            501 => 'Not implemented'
        );

        header('HTTP/1.1 '.$resultsArr['Code'].' '.
            $http_response_code[$resultsArr['Code'] ]);
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo($jsonStr);
    die();
?>
```

There are the contents of the HTML file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git1.js"></script>
        <script>

        var jsonStr = '{"dummyRequest":true}';

        // ajax call starts
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: 'data.php',
            data: {
                request: jsonStr
            },
            success: function(data) {

                if (typeof data == 'string') {
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                }

                $('#retJson').html(''); // Clear #retJson div
                $('#retJson').append('data = {<br />');
                for (var key in data) {
                    $('#retJson').append(key + ': ' + data[key] + '<br />');
                }
                $('#retJson').append('}');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                $('#retJson').html(''); // Clear #retJson div
                $('#retJson').append('error = ' + errorThrown); 
            } 
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="retJson">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work I am still getting my Failed No Data

Comment: I've tested the entire use case and updated the code.